# Use variables from iPython in a script

Tags: python, ipython

I'd like to pass variables I've defined in iPython into a python script.

For example:

```
In [1]: import demo
In [2]: x = [1, 2, 3]
In [3]: y = [1, 2, 3]
In [4]: rtp x y
```

Where the script is:

```
import IPython.ipapi
ip = IPython.ipapi.get()

def run_this_plot(*args):
    """ Run
    Examples
    In [1]: import demo
    In [2]: rtp x y <z> 
    Where x, y, and z are numbers of any type
    """
    print "args: ", args
    # Do something here with args, such as plot them

# Activate the extension
ip.expose_magic("rtp", run_this_plot)
```

So I'd like the values from x and y in iPython, whatever they might be (ints, ranges, etc) to be seen from the script, which right now only sees the string "x y".

How might I obtain these values in the transfer from iPython to a script? If it's not possible, what do people usually do as a workaround?

Thanks!
--Erin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it useful to browse the [source](http://ipython.scipy.org/svn/ipython/ipython/trunk/IPython/Magic.py) of the IPython.Magic module for clues. It would appear you can only get one string argument into a custom magic method. But I can't seem to find a doc reference to confirm.

While I imagine there's a better way to accomplish this, the following should work for your specific example:

```
import IPython.ipapi
ip = IPython.ipapi.get()

def run_this_plot(self, arg_s=''):
    """ Run
    Examples
    In [1]: import demo
    In [2]: rtp x y <z> 
    Where x, y, and z are numbers of any type
    """
    args = []
    for arg in arg_s.split():
        try:
            args.append(self.shell.user_ns[arg])
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invalid argument: %r" % arg)
    print "args: ", args
    # Do something here with args, such as plot them

# Activate the extension
ip.expose_magic("rtp", run_this_plot)
```

Comment: Thank you- this is exactly what I was looking for. With x and y values set, rtp x y now prints the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine when I did

```
rtp x, y
```

Comment: That's strange. I still get a string output- 'x, y' when I use that line. Does python recognize the correct types of your x, y variables as well?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 and iPython 0.10.1 Win 32.